# how to rotate the orientation of my monitor in OSX 10.8?

Tags: display, screen

My girlfriend just bought a great monitor (EIZO CG223W) for her macbook, which you can rotate 90º in portrait mode.

The screens didn't flip along, and I couldn't find a setting in the system preferences.

I remember (in pre 10.8) there used to be a setting in the screen panel, but it's vanished.## Heading ##

Comment: Which monitor is this (My Dell is detected by OSX and has an option in System Preferences->Display)

Comment: it's an  EIZO CG223W. OSX doesn't automatically detects it. Did OSX 10.8.2 auto-detected yours? Interesting.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After some research i found [this blog](http://roadzy.blogspot.nl/2012/10/how-do-i-rotate-my-screen-on-external.html), which perfectly detailed explains how to get this hidden setting:

1. Open the system preferences
2. Hold down the **command** and **option** keys while clicking the display
   icon
3. Next locate the screen adjustments on the external monitor and you
   will notice now there is an option called "Rotation".
4. Choose 90 Degrees and now your monitor is in portrait mode.

Thanks roadzy and [OSXdaily](http://osxdaily.com/2010/12/28/rotate-mac-screen-orientation/)!

Comment: One up for source and self answering. Thanks for keeping up the sharing.